# Can you prompt a user for an input so they can save files as they prefer?

Tags: python, input

I want my users to be able to save the files as they wish. This program I am writing is going to be used by many different people for hundreds of files. I was hoping this was possible

```
filename = input("Enter Desired File Name:")
F = open(filename,'wb')
```

As a trial run, I ran it and input the name Hello_Buddy.csv
and recieved this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Bud\Desktop\School\Project Data\OWLeS\Radiosonde
Data\Python\Simple\Moving Average.py", line 44, in <module>
    filename = input("Enter Desired File Name:")
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'Hello_Buddy' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input):

`filename = raw_input("Enter Desired File Name:")`

python will try to run `input()`  as an expression `raw_input` returns a string.

F.Y.I there is no `raw_input` in python 3  it has been renamed to`input()`.

The difference between `input` and  `raw_input`:

```
In [23]: input()
4+2
Out[23]: 6

In [24]: raw_input()
4+2
Out[24]: '4+2'
```

basically `input` is the same as:

```
In [25]: eval(raw_input())
4+2
Out[25]: 6
```